# How to read, combine, save two jpeg files in android?

Tags: java, android

I have stored in my android device (for example in directory Example) two jpeg file 1.jpg and 2.jpg of dimension 64x64.
I want to merge (put one near the other) these two files and save in the same directory the resulting file 3.jpg of dimension 128x64.
Which is the easiest way to do this?
I tried to find some examples, but I have not find the solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) of the appropriate size and [draw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) each bitmap onto it in the desired configuration.

Edit: [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863551/597849).

Edit: To load an image from file storage into a Bitmap, you can use [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).

Comment: OK thanks. I have jpg instead of bitmap and I do not know how to read them in memmory before merging.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I'm able to do this. I'll try. At moment I can consider the answer completed.