# How to merge to two bitmap one over another programmatically?

Tags: android

I have try this

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap ScaledBitmap, Bitmap bit) {

    int X = bit.getWidth();
    int Y = bit.getHeight();

    Scaled_X = ScaledBitmap.getWidth();
    scaled_Y = ScaledBitmap.getHeight();

    System.out.println("Combined Images");

    System.out.println("Bit :" + X + "/t" + Y);

    System.out.println("SCaled_Bitmap :" + Scaled_X + "\t" + scaled_Y);

    overlaybitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(ScaledBitmap.getWidth(),
            ScaledBitmap.getHeight(), ScaledBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlaybitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ScaledBitmap, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bit, new Matrix(), null);

    return overlaybitmap;
}
```

its not working

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863518/combining-two-bitmap-image-side-by-side

Comment: hey thanks for reply sasikumar let me try this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code sniplet and tweak as per your requirements

```
 private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

make sure bmp1 is the bigger than bmp2