# android- Show multiple images in one imageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-glide, circleimage

I need to create a chat view like below image. if there are members more than 3, need to show number. But **images need to retrieved from URL**. i have done a research but can't find any example. here i have set one Image in a imageView.Can anyone help me?

[image]

ChatAdapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_list_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_background"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center"
                android:gravity="end|center"
                android:text="@string/delete"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_image"
                    android:layout_width="50sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/chat_name"
                        style="@style/defaultTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre_extra_bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
                        style="@style/defaultTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/abhaya_libre_semi_bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_date"
                    style="@style/defaultTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ChatAdapter.java

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ChatList> chatLists;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ChatList> chatLists) {
        this.context = context;
        this.chatLists = chatLists;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_adapter, null, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ChatList item = chatLists.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.message.setText(item.getMessage());
        holder.date.setText(item.getDate());

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(item.getImage())
                .fitCenter()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatMessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("chatname", item.getName());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        chatLists.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreItem(ChatList item, int position) {
        chatLists.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public List<ChatList> getData() {
        return chatLists;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatLists.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView image;
        AppCompatTextView name, message, date;
        public LinearLayout forground, background;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_image);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_name);
            message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_message);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_date);
            forground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);
            background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
        }
    }
}
```

ChatList.java

```
public class ChatList {

    String name, message, date, image;

    public ChatList(String name, String message, String date, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
        this.date = date;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

here is my chatListData

```
ChatList list = new ChatList("Ellen, Grandpa + 1", "Thanks for letting us know!", "Jan 04", "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/senior-adult-male-laughing-portrait-he-is-90-years-old-picture-id155357459?k=6&m=155357459&s=612x612&w=0&h=E_uK43zNoAnt9ohSdYMbNgCyFJliuKIzTynduh7d-Ck=");
        chatLists.add(list);
 list = new ChatList("Ellen, Grandpa + 1", "Thanks for letting us know!", "Jan 04", "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/senior-adult-male-laughing-portrait-he-is-90-years-old-picture-id155357459?k=6&m=155357459&s=612x612&w=0&h=E_uK43zNoAnt9ohSdYMbNgCyFJliuKIzTynduh7d-Ck=");
        chatLists.add(list);
 list = new ChatList("Ellen, Grandpa + 1", "Thanks for letting us know!", "Jan 04", "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/senior-adult-male-laughing-portrait-he-is-90-years-old-picture-id155357459?k=6&m=155357459&s=612x612&w=0&h=E_uK43zNoAnt9ohSdYMbNgCyFJliuKIzTynduh7d-Ck=");
        chatLists.add(list);
```

Comment: https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/MultiImageView

Comment: @UsamaAltaf thanks for the reply. But this library don't have the number facility right?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Yes. please help me if you find any library with that feature. thanks

Comment: you can use `Canvas` to create `Bitmap` with multiple images please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863551/7085389

Comment: You can use multiple image views and le them visible or invisible  on  the basis of scenario.